Need to know jest dom setup in plain vanilla javascript
i created an todo app in vanilla javascript now i needed to test that using jest but the thing jest-environment is not working on that. i need proper procedure to setup get done
package.json
{
  "name": "todo-list-e2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "primary-violet:7743DB;\r primary-white:F7EFE5\r secondary-white:FFFBF5\r primary-yellow:ffc100",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },

  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.6",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.1.0"
  }
}

jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};

